# How to load sub categories into joomla from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, components

I am messing around with the com_content/view/article component.
I am trying to add all subdirectories to the class for view.html.php, I can't seem to get the information out of the database. I've been successful at getting The article category and parent category. I tried editing model/article.php I added a loop that would query->select and query->join but I was not sure how to check if the database had more subcategories.

The model gets the article info. uses catID to join the category, then it joins the subcategory and that's it. I want to try and loop through until each subcategory loaded has 0 or null as their parent_id.

The reason why I am doing this is because I want to have opengraph information for each category. In my view.html.php I have a code that sets opengraph description to the article, if there is none in database, it goes to category, if there is none there it loads it from the menu, (not sure if I have that working properly yet), if not then from configuration.php. Well I would like to add in their before menu, subcategories.

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at Stackexchange. You will have a better change to get an answer if you ask your question there. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the article category as $catid, this should get all subcategories

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = "select c2.* from #__categories c, #__categories c2
where c.id={$catid} and c.lft<c2.lft and c2.rgt<c.rgt";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$categories = $db->loadObjectList();
```